# Using Cookies to track number of visits to a site with Javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, tracking

First I will start off by saying I'm a newbie in Javascript and I'm trying to track this information for a website I created.

I want to create a cookie called "counter" and track the number of times a user has visited the page. I have set up an input with an id="counter" where I want to display this number. By default the number will always be set to "1" even if the user has never visited the page. Lastly, I want the cookie to expire a year from that date however I think I may have solved that on my own. Please let me know if I messed that up!

I would really appreciate it if I can get ideas on how to write this code or examples doing the same thing I'm trying to do. Thanks

Making the cookie expire in one year from the current date:

```
    var expiry = new Date();

    expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime()+(365*24*60*60*1000));
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of places where this has been done before:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/legacy/beyond/javascript/cookiecountexplanation.html
(this one includes a VERY detailed explanation)

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3461991

http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/cookie6.htm

**Worth noting:**

This will only track the number of visits the user has made **IN THE SAME BROWSER**.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks. And yes I know it only tracks the visits in one browser.

Comment: Also worth noting: cookies can be spoofed by the client, so you should never really "trust" them.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous libraries out there for tracking cookies. I've used jquery-cookie before. Very simple, and did the trick for me.

[jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: Do you have a good library using only Javascript? Unfortunately it has to be in Javascript :(